# Create new Angular application with CLI takes too much time

Tags: angular

Whenever I run "ng new ProjectName" CLI command it takes couple of minutes to create the project.

Is there a faster way to create a project like copying an existing project and changing some parameters?
As far as I understand ng new downloads lots of modules.

Comment: there are actually a good number of dependencies. What you are looking for is called a "boilerplate" (a basic project that can be run and gives something like "hello, this a app"). Probably, this boilerplate doesn't include the packages, on ly the reference. You will have to do something like `npm install` to get the required dependencies, and think it should take some time too, if you don't have a high capacity internet access. But anyway, you can try other, and maybe simpler, boilerplates than the one created by angular CLI.

Answer (score 13):

You can keep an original/unmodified as a template:

`ng new AngularCLITemplate`

and when you build future projects you can skip installing node_modules:

`ng new --skip-install true NewProjectName`

then copy and paste your node_modules folder from the template into your new project. Afterward you'll want to npm install:

`cd NewProjectName && npm install` to make sure it caches the npm module locations.

It will be close to the same time to build a new project, since downloading the node_modules doesn't take as much time as simply writing them to the disk during installation (which the copy/paste will have to do), but it might save a minute or two on an older machine or slower internet.

Comment: Thanks for this though copying node_modules took 4 minutes.

Comment: here is a trick, once you have a fresh copy zip node_modules folder, and unzip it in new project, though unzipping would still take some time, but is faster compared to copy/paste. for even better performance use 7zip or winrar.

Comment: "slower internet" can be very daunting with a rural satellite with 20GB data cap for decent speed. And then, we don't want to spend 300MB of duplicate download per project

Answer (score 2):

hi bro this is because angular cli installs the dependencies running

```
npm install
```

but to make it faster you can use yarn.

If you haven't installed yet

```
npm install -g yarn
```

this use npm, other ways of installing in the following link.

https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/

```
ng new --skip-install true NewProjectName // will avoid npm install 

ng set --global packageManager=yarn
```

using yarn will decrease your speed at least by half, if you want to get back to npm.

```
ng set --global packageManager=npm
```

Comment: I guess you mean that yarn will increase the speed for project creation by half.